# Is FBSDKLoginManager or FBSDKLoginButton compatible with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, facebook-login, xamarin.auth

I heard that some local UX (per platform) may not work with Xamarin Forms.

Is it possible to leverage [FBSDKLoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced) or FBSDKLoginButton with Xamarin Forms?

I considered using the Xamarin Auth, but it uses a pop up window, doesn't leverage Facebook's Javascript SDK, and furthermore it won't transparently sign on if the user is already signed in using iOS's Facebook app.

Comment: Possible?, of course..any particular problem that you are having? Using Platform-specific binding projects, Form's dependency service and custom renderers you can *fully* integrate Facebooks *native* APIs. It is slightly time-consuming to setup for iOS and Android, but worth it if you need a custom login flow.

Comment: @SushiHangover my concern was that since Facebook displays custom UX in a custom ViewController this might conflict with Xamarin forms.

Comment: No issue assuming you understand the Xamarin.Form's life cycle and iOS ViewController life cycle. This is done all the time, i.e. A Form's *app* (which is just a `ViewController`) launching a doc picker, the camera view, etc... These are all ViewControllers launched from another ViewController...

Comment: OK so this conflicts or supersedes my previous information. I was an Enterprise customer prior to the MSFT acquisition and they said that it wasn't possible to mix a ViewController with Xamarin Forms. @sushihangover

Comment: If you do not understand the Page/View/ViewController life cycles within mobile development, then I could understand someone *steering* you away from it, but yes of course it is possible. There are active Store-based apps using my Facebook integration using their native SDKs...  In a very basic example, create a Form's dependency service and launch a custom modal ViewController from it, navigate away from it and you are "back" in the Form's app.

Comment: This is no different then a Form's plugin launching a `UIImagePickerController`, etc... Now integrating custom Navigation Controllers is also possible as I've done it, BUT if you need that much "native" interaction w/ a Forms-based app, *SKIP* Forms and write your UI's native. Personally I write native UIs for non-LOB apps and steer clients away from them also. Forms' is a great a *tool* and I use it where/when I can, but sometimes the amount of hoop jumping to get the app's UI experience to meet the design requirements is to high, so I go native...